# Cloudant Query: how to obtain a count of documents matching a selector?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Using [Cloudant Query](https://examples.cloudant.com/movies-demo/_design/app/index.html) I would like to obtain a count of the number of documents which match a query, without returning the actual documents. Is there a way to do this with the current API, or are there plans to add it in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get only the # of documents matched, but you can use the `fields` parameter to restrict what's returned to a single property of the document, then count those.